# Compare the contingency table of two dataframes

Tags: r

Here is the original dataframe:

```
set.seed(100)
toydata <- data.frame(A = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      B = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      C = sample(1:50,50,replace = T)

)
```

Below is the function which can swap values:

```
derangement <- function(x){
  if(max(table(x)) > length(x)/2) return(NA)
  while(TRUE){
    y <- sample(x)
    if(sum(y == x)<3) return(y)
  }
}

swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
  inx <- which(x < n)
  y <- derangement(x[inx])
  if(length(y) == 1) return(NA) 
  x[inx] <- y
  x
}
```

`toy` is the new dataframe after swapping

```
toy <- toydata    # Work with a copy
toy[] <- lapply(toydata, swapFun)
```

I want to compare the contingency tables of these two dataframe by the difference of sum, which means:

```
table1<-table(toydata$A,toydata$B)
table2<-table(toy$A,toy$B)
SUM1<-sum(abs(table1-table2))

table3<-table(toydata$A,toydata$C)
table4<-table(toy$A,toy$C)
SUM2<-sum(abs(table3-table4))

table5<-table(toydata$B,toydata$C)
table6<-table(toy$C,toy$C)
SUM3<-sum(abs(table5-table6))
```

`SUM1`+`SUM2`+`SUM3` is what I want to have. Can I get it more conviniently because sometimes the dataframe  has many columns.

How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your problem is that you need to find all the ways to construct couples from `n` columns. For this you can use the function `combn(n,2)` (in your example n = 3). However very quickly this can yield a huge number of combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# your function to compare contingency tables
f = function(x,y){
  table1<-table(toydata[,x],toydata[,y])
  table2<-table(toy[,x],toy[,y])
  sum(abs(table1-table2))
}

# vectorise your function
f = Vectorize(f)

combn(x=names(toydata),
      y=names(toydata), 2) %>%             # create all combinations of your column names
  t() %>%                                  # transpose
  data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = F) %>%  # save as dataframe
  filter(X1 != X2) %>%                     # exclude pairs of same column
  mutate(SumAbs = f(X1,X2))                # apply function

#   X1 X2 SumAbs
# 1  A  B     14
# 2  A  C     26
# 3  B  C     22
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error                                                                                                           
`  
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-conformable arrays.
` when run the last few lines.....

Comment: Is this on your whole dataset or for the specific example you posted?

Comment: on my whole data set which has 10 columns.

Comment: Have you tried your example first? Did it work there?

Comment: Then you have to spot the difference between your example and your full dataset. I have no idea how it looks like! :) Any `NA` values in any columns? Are all your columns numeric?

Comment: my full dataset is `set.seed(100)
toydata <- data.frame(A = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      B = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      C = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      D = sample(1:50,50,replace = T),
                      E = sample(1:50,50,replace = T)
)`

Comment: `E` column from `toy` data frame is full of `NA`s. It doesn't have swapped values from column `E` in `toydata` and the tables we create have different dimensions.

Comment: Oh, no...I do not want that to be `NA`. Why does that happen? I will fix it.

Comment: Yes, it seems it must have swapped values from the other `E` column so the tables can have the same dimensions. If you fix that the code should work :)